# Initialization class constant by JSON parsing in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I write Rails application and one controller's methods require some data which I prefer storing in JSON file.

I placed JSON file to `assets/data/somedata.json` and tried to initialize class constant by JSON parsing:

```
require "open-uri"
require "json"

class SomethingsController < ApplicationController
  def view
  end

private
  SOMEDATA = JSON.parse(open("http://localhost:3000/assets/somedata.json").read(nil))

  def method_using_somedata
    value = SOMEDATA["key"]
    # ...
  end
end
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. When I try to get somethings#view, Rails application don't answer.

Evidently, I try to solve my task wrong.

Is there a good way to get what I need?

Comment: Try reading the file from the filesystem rather than using a HTTP request to get it maybe?

Comment: Hmmm. I replaced `open("http://localhost:3000/assets/somedata.json")` by `File.open(Rails.root.join("app/assets/data/somedata.json"))` -- and it fix issue. By why my version didn't work? The file somedata.json is available with HTTP protocol -- I tested it via `wget`. I don't see the problem.

Comment: Make sure to close your file

Comment: Yes, I sure. Wget can get somedata.json, but Rails controller can't.